# Odd bug, invisible charaters - hidden quotes and space

Tags: javascript, arrays, xmlhttprequest

I'm reading a text file via `XMLHttpRequest` and grabbing each line via `responseText.split('\n')`. After that, i'm storing in an array each set of characters separated by tab via `shift().split('\t')` of only the first element from the initial split. I then assign based on those entries, dynamic object properties to.. an object.
Code looks like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var response = xhr.responseText;
                intermediary = response.trim().split('\n'), //split by new line
                headers = intermediary.shift().split('\t'), //remove table headers, but keep reference
                headersLength = headers.length;

            //WEIRD STUFF TEST
            o = new Object;
            for(var i=0; i < headers.length; i++){
                var a = headers[i];
                o[a] = '';
            }
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(o);
            //END OF WEIRD STUFF TEST

//rest of code
```

Now onto the weird part. When i log the headers array i get say: `["Bob", "Max"]` but when i create the object properties i get `{bob: "", "Max": ""}` - **notice the quotes around Max**.
What's even weirder is - and it led me to a fix - is that Firefox does not put the quotes and IE (Edge) adds an extra space before the last quote `"Max "`.
The fix is do do a `shift().trim().split('\t')` - basically, make sure the shift does not carry anything along with it.

I've enabled all hidden characters, tabs, spaces on multiple editors and there's nothing shady in the files. I'm on Windows 10 (don't know if it matters, but perhaps it does).

What i want to know is why this is happening? A detailed explanation (can be as technical as you can make it) would be much appreciated. What i'm thinking is causing the behavior divergence between the browsers is the fact that you can't have a property name end with a space, but why is a white space sneaked in there in the first place - seeing as nothing sees it in the file?

If i'm an idiot and the answer is right in front of me, that works as well.

NOTE: doing `.replace(' ','')` or `.trim()` on `headers[i]` does not work.
NOTE 2: Seeing the log(comments) it's quite obvious why removing spaces was not working. Question still stands though - how did a carriage return get in there and is not visible?

Comment: You can write a function to dump out the character codes in a string using the `.charCodeAt()` function.

Comment: Please show us what `console.log(JSON.stringify(headers), JSON.stringify(o))` gives

Comment: @Bergi ["BrandID","Name\r"] {"BrandID":"","Name\r":""} - output of log

Comment: @Pointy good idea.

Comment: The `\r` is a carriage return.

Comment: @Pointy Indeed, i was assuming it was a space, but now that i've seen the log, it's quite obvious why removing spaces was not working. It does not explain however why it did work when popping the first element via `.shift()`, not does it explain where it comes from. At least, i don't have an explaination.

Comment: You're splitting on `\n` - the line terminators in the source file are probably the two-character sequence `\r\n`. Thus, the very first string in the file is OK, because there's no line terminator before it, but then strings at the ends of lines get that `\r` tacked on at the end.

Comment: Fair point, however this extra carriage return can be between two properties, say {"a": "", "b\r": "", "c": ""} - i'd understand if it were only at the end. Perhaps when the file was made, they concatenated two lines and somehow a carriage return was left there floating, in the middle. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!